# Error report for global use of composer under Windows system

Tags: php, composer-php

I have tried to install composer according to the three methods provided by composer's official website. There is no problem in executing composer - V under PHP installation directory. However, if you execute composer - V in any directory in any way, the following error will be reported repeatedly:
[This is the error output from the implementation of composer - V and the PHP version number](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQJgE.png)
I don't know if the latest version of composer is not uninstalled and there are residual error. This question has made my head swell. Which international friend can take a look at it!

Comment: It's really hard to understand the error message because it's not in English. Could you please translate it?

Comment: Thanks a million！I will translate the Chinese in the picture below.                       
The meaning of the first sentence is probably
'/' is not an internal or external command, nor a runnable program or batch file
The second sentence is the option to stop the operation.                                          In fact, mine is also machine translation, ha ha!

Comment: Please add the error text in english and in text form to your question by editing it

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been solved. I used the software installation method from the [official Composer website](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md). When setting the environment variables, I put the composer path first, and then I can use composer in any directory, although I don't know what happened in the end. This is a screenshot of the environment variables configured in my Windows 10.

[image: This is a screenshot of the environment variables configured on my computer]

Comment: Please add some further explanation - what is the "software installation method" you are referring to?